# SimpleXML node with spaces and equal signs in the node name

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an xml document that contains spaces and equal signs in the node names. I'm trying to use SimpleXML to extract the data from those nodes but it returns blank no matter what I try.

A sample of the xml document

```
  <code><away>
  <radio>url.here</radio> 
  <live bitrate="1">url.here</live> 
  <live bitrate="0">url.here</live> 
  </away></code>
```

I have tried using both`echo "<td>".$node->away->{'live bitrate="1"'}."</td>";
echo "<td>".$node->away->{'live'}->{'bitrate="1"'}."</td>";`

Comment: Uh... I don't know how to tell you this, but those aren't "spaces and equal signs in the node names"; those are *attributes*. http://w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function I use to convert the SimpleXML object to an array:

```
        public function simpleXMLToArray($xml,
                    $flattenValues=true,
                    $flattenAttributes = true,
                    $flattenChildren=true,
                    $valueKey='@value',
                    $attributesKey='@attributes',
                    $childrenKey='@children'){

            $return = array();
            if(!($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement)){return $return;}
            $name = $xml->getName();
            $_value = trim((string)$xml);
            if(strlen($_value)==0){$_value = null;};

            if($_value!==null){
                    if(!$flattenValues){$return[$valueKey] = $_value;}
                    else{$return = $_value;}
            }

            $children = array();
            $first = true;
            foreach($xml->children() as $elementName => $child){
                    $value = $this->simpleXMLToArray($child, $flattenValues, $flattenAttributes, $flattenChildren, $valueKey, $attributesKey, $childrenKey);
                    if(isset($children[$elementName])){
                            if($first){
                                    $temp = $children[$elementName];
                                    unset($children[$elementName]);
                                    $children[$elementName][] = $temp;
                                    $first=false;
                            }
                            $children[$elementName][] = $value;
                    }
                    else{
                            $children[$elementName] = $value;
                    }
            }
            if(count($children)>0){
                    if(!$flattenChildren){$return[$childrenKey] = $children;}
                    else{$return = array_merge($return,$children);}
            }

            $attributes = array();
            foreach($xml->attributes() as $name=>$value){
                    $attributes[$name] = trim($value);
            }
            if(count($attributes)>0){
                    if(!$flattenAttributes){$return[$attributesKey] = $attributes;}
                    else{$return = array_merge($return, $attributes);}
            }

            return $return;
    }
```